# How I can pass environment variables to my flask application

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I am new to Python and writing a simple flask api which will connect to azure cosmos DB and return some response.

I want to pass db connection string as environment variable as going forward I need to dockerize this application.

So I am not sure how I can pass this connection string to my Flask application as environment variable and how to run and test my Flask application from command windows.

Below is my piece of code.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

APP = Flask(__name__)
APP.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
connectionstring = os.environ['connectionstring']

@APP.route('/getdata')
def view_registered_guests():
print("Inside method");

table_service = TableService(connection_string=connectionstring)
table_name = 'tablebasics'
entity = table_service.get_entity(table_name, 'Harp', '2')
print(entity['email'])
print(entity['phone'])
return "Email: "+entity['email'] +" phone no: "+ entity['phone'];

if __name__ == '__main__':
APP.run(debug=True)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/2/

Comment: @Abhinay nope, the OP is talking about __environment__ variables.

Comment: I dont want to use config file. I need to pass this connection string as env variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os` module

```
os.environ["connectionstring"]
```

You can set environment variables in windows cmd using `SET`

`set connectionstring=SOMETHING`

Comment: That is already there.. connectionstring = os.environ['connectionstring'].

Comment: User already using environment variable. Please check code above.

Comment: I am not sure if my code is correct. If it is then can someone tell how I can run it from cmd and pass this env variable or if there is other way to run and test it

Answer (score 0):

To test this i just added "connectionstring" variable and its value in system environment variables (System variables) and ran my py file and it worked.

Thanks everyone for you hints.